# Transfer of existing Git Repo into GitHub with large Files to be added to the LFS

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I have a Git repository which I have stored on a server currently, however I wish to move this to GitHub. I know this repo contains 4/5 files which I have would want to be stored in the LFS.
What I have done so far is:

- Installed LFS.
- Setup the tracking of the files I want to move into it & pushed this to the remote (though I'm not sure any changes occurred).
- Then I changed my remote to the new blank GitHub repo.

When I push I still get a message about the files being too big for GitHub. (The biggest is 338MB).

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to also move the history to use git-lfs. Read [*Migrate a Git repo into Git LFS with BFG*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/migrate_to_git_lfs.html).

Comment: Git LFS now has its own tool for converting large files in the Git history into Git LFS pointer files, [`git lfs migrate`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn#migrate-local-history).

Comment: Be aware also that GitHub has a 1GB per-account Git LFS storage limit and 1GB per month per account Git LFS download limit. See [About storage and bandwidth usage](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage). It sounds like you might hit this limit if your files are hundreds of MB large. You can pay to upgrade: [Upgrading Git LFS](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/setting-up-and-managing-billing-and-payments-on-github/upgrading-git-large-file-storage)